# Will symbolic links created in unix (linux/osx) still working in windows?

Tags: windows, unix, operating-system, filesystems, symlink

Is it possible to create a symbolic link with relative path in linux/osx, move the complete folder to windows system and still be able to use the links?

Say a structure is following:

```
> ln -s ../c/e d

./a
  |
  |-/b
  |  |
  |  |-d -> ../c/e // symlink
  |  
  |-/c
     |
     |-e // original file
```

so `./a/b/d` is a symlink to `./a/c/e`. So will this still work on windows, if I will move the whole `./a` directory there?

## Update:

I found some related questions, but there is no information about relative paths and osx case or they are a bit outdated (2007):

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/63172/does-windows-recognize-linuxs-symbolic-links
- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-general-1/copy-symbolic-links-from-linux-to-windows-554000/
- http://bytes.com/topic/unix/answers/620128-how-copy-symbolic-link-linux-windows

Comment: osx: `hfs`, linux: `ext4`, windows: `ntfs`. (Just common desktop FSs)

Comment: @MartinPrikryl: will the link work as symbolic link also in windows, or you just mean, that you can copy it to windows and back again? does it also work with relative paths?

Comment: @Goofy: nope, I just use it on linux only for now.

Comment: @static No the links won't work on Windows, I've misunderstood your question. Deleting my comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, on Windows the symbolic link will just show as a file containing the location of the file the symbolic link pointed to.